# what is the difference between a load callback and list callback in the i18n hook_i18n_object_info() function?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am learning how to use the i18n module to translate a module. In `hook_i18n_object_info()` implementations, I have noticed other modules using list callback or load callback.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list callback is a callback that returns all the objects of a specific type; for example, for content types, the list callback is [`node_type_get_types()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7.x).
A load callback is a callback that loads a single object of that specific type; for content types, the load callback is [`node_type_get_type()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_type/7.x).